# Which twitter API should I use to fetch all nearby users based on my geo location?

Tags: twitter

*Twitter API should I use to fetch all nearby users based on my Geological Location.*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use this https://dev.twitter.com/rest/reference/get/search/tweets just pass the geocode.